# Passing Variables To/From Function

Tags: javascript

I am attempting to create a code that generates faces and displays them as part of an audited Coursera.com course. There are variables generated outside of the function that I would like to pass into it, and then get some out. My attempt:

```
var numberOfFaces = 5;
var theLeftSide = document.getElementById("leftSide");
var theImg = document.createElement("img");
theImg.src = "smile.png";    

function generateFaces(numberOfFaces, theLeftSide, theImg) {

        for (i = 0; i < numberOfFaces; i++) {
            var leftPosition = Math.floor(Math.random() * 400);

            var topPosition = Math.floor(Math.random() * 400);

            theImg.style.left = leftPosition + "px";
            theImg.style.top = topPosition + "px";
            theLeftSide.appendChild(theImg.cloneNode());

        };
        var theRightSide = document.getElementById("rightSide");
        var leftSideImages = theLeftSide.cloneNode(true);
        leftSideImages.removeChild(leftSideImages.lastChild);
        theRightSide.appendChild(leftSideImages.cloneNode(true));
        return leftSideImages;
    }

window.onload = generateFaces;
```

This didn't feel right as I wasn't defining any variables in the

```
window.onload = generateFaces;
```

Next, I tried a button

```
<input id="clickMe" type="button" value="clickme" onclick="generateFaces(numberOfFaces, theLeftSide, theImg);" />
```

A push in the right direction would be appreciated. The code works if I define the variables in the function, which is an accomplishment so far!

Comment: Why are you defining those variables inside as local and outside as global?

Comment: Sorry, I meant if I define them inside the function instead of outside, my code works. It was how I was testing the function originally, but now I'd like to use some variables in other places.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe that the problem you are having is that you are trying to access a dom element before the page is loaded.

```
var theLeftSide = document.getElementById("leftSide");
```

Try declaring it inside the function where you need it, since it is not used outside the function anyway.

```
var numberOfFaces = 5;
var theImg = document.createElement("img");
theImg.src = "smile.png";    

function generateFaces(numberOfFaces, theLeftSide, theImg) {

        var theLeftSide = document.getElementById("leftSide");

        for (i = 0; i < numberOfFaces; i++) {
            var leftPosition = Math.floor(Math.random() * 400);

            var topPosition = Math.floor(Math.random() * 400);

            theImg.style.left = leftPosition + "px";
            theImg.style.top = topPosition + "px";
            theLeftSide.appendChild(theImg.cloneNode());

        };
        var theRightSide = document.getElementById("rightSide");
        var leftSideImages = theLeftSide.cloneNode(true);
        leftSideImages.removeChild(leftSideImages.lastChild);
        theRightSide.appendChild(leftSideImages.cloneNode(true));
        return leftSideImages;
    }

window.onload = generateFaces;
```

Comment: Gregor! Thank you so much!

Answer (score 0):

```
var numberOfFaces = 5;
var theLeftSide = document.getElementById("leftSide");
var theImg = document.createElement("img");
theImg.src = "smile.png";    

function generateFaces() {

        for (i = 0; i < numberOfFaces; i++) {
            var leftPosition = Math.floor(Math.random() * 400);

            var topPosition = Math.floor(Math.random() * 400);

            theImg.style.left = leftPosition + "px";
            theImg.style.top = topPosition + "px";
            theLeftSide.appendChild(theImg.cloneNode());

        };
        var theRightSide = document.getElementById("rightSide");
        var leftSideImages = theLeftSide.cloneNode(true);
        leftSideImages.removeChild(leftSideImages.lastChild);
        theRightSide.appendChild(leftSideImages.cloneNode(true));
        return leftSideImages;
    }

window.onload = generateFaces();
```

don't put the var's in your function to pass them to it.  only define them globally if that is the way you will set them.

If you want to be able to dynamically generate the var's then you must put them in the function.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure why you define variables at the global level (which is not a good practice please keep in mind), just to pass them to the function in the `onload` function, however, if you use those variables also elsewhere, and want your function be with parameters, and run `onload` with this variables passed as parameters, that's the way:

```
var numberOfFaces = 5;
var theLeftSide = document.getElementById("leftSide");
var theImg = document.createElement("img");
theImg.src = "smile.png";    

function generateFaces(numberOfFaces, theLeftSide, theImg) {

        (...)
    }

window.onload = function() {
   generateFaces(numberOfFaces, theLeftSide, theImg);
};
```

If those variables are rather static, and you don't need them elsewhere, just put them inside of the function:

```
function generateFaces() {
   var numberOfFaces = 5;
   var theLeftSide = document.getElementById("leftSide");
   var theImg = document.createElement("img");
   theImg.src = "smile.png";
        (...)
    }

window.onload = generateFaces;
```

Comment: Thank you for your help!

Comment: Please upvote answers which you found helpful :)

Comment: Alex, sorry I didn't see this. I upvoted but because my reputation is low it says that they do not show up publicly!